# Is a vector multiplied with its transpose always positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a vector which is
$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&\dots&a_n\end{bmatrix}$

Then, $A'A$ would be
\begin{bmatrix}a_1^2&a_1a_2&..\\ a_2  a_1&a_2^2&\dots\\ \dots&\dots&\dots\\\dots&\dots&a_n^2\end{bmatrix}

which is a symmetric matrix with nonnegative diagonal elements.
Are these properties enough to say that A' * A is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Any matrix multiplied by its adjoint is positive semidefinite. For real matrices, the adjoint is just the transpose. A vector is just a row or column matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is your row vector then for any row vector $v$:

$$v(a^{\top}a)v^{\top}=(va^{\top})(av^{\top})=(v\cdot a)^2\geq 0.$$

So $a^{\top}a$ is positive semidefinite.